# Sizing individual flexbox items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am experimenting with flexboxes and the tutorial from codebin and I want the layout to be a full screen flexbox layout.

The Jfiddle can't emulate the 100% stretch thing for some reason but the screenshot seems to make the issue clear.

But I want the header to have a predefined height without it stretching and there is a lot of empty space in the elements that don't seem to wrap itself to it's content.

This goes for all the items really. I would want a layout where I can define the height of items without creating non wrapped gaps in the process. % doesn't seem to be working.

[image: Flexbox not sizing correctly]

http://jsfiddle.net/rhkahtaa/

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        display:flex;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;  

      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;

      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      align-items:stretch;
    }

    .wrapper > * {
      padding: 10px;
      flex: 1 100%;
      flex-basis: 1 auto;
    }

    .header {
      height:20%;
      flex-shrink:1;
      background: red;
    }

    .footer {
      background: green;
    }

    .main {
      width:80%;
      text-align: left;
      background: blue;
    }

    .aside-1 {
      width:10%;
      background: gold;
    }

    .aside-2 {
        width:10%;
      background: pink;
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
      .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
      .main    { flex: 2 0px; }
      .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
      .main    { order: 2; }
      .aside-2 { order: 3; }
      .footer  { order: 4; }
    }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="header">Header</header>
        <article class="main">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
        </article>
        <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
        <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
        <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: JSfiddle with stretch added - [http://jsfiddle.net/rhkahtaa/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/rhkahtaa/2/) - Looking into a solution

Comment: Thank you! I am fiddling myself too as we speak but I can't seem to find a solution. Not REALLY.